# What is progression in test automation? What open source tool could be used to design automation framework for that?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, quality-assurance

I 've been working in automation for the last 8 years. Recently, I have come across the term "Progression" in test automation. I've learned basics but still, I am not sure how to implement this concept in our DevOps test automation pipeline. As it's suggesting automation test case is ready before code deliver to QA & which tool to consider for designing front end web-based & API automation framework?

Reference links:

https://opkey.com/blog-detail.php/What-is-Progressive-Automation?

https://www.techarcis.com/2915-2progressive-test-automation-to-expedite-the-testing-process/

Comment: Please share the source. Not a familiar term to me so prob. not a common industry term given my experience

Comment: here is a reference link:https://opkey.com/blog-detail.php/What-is-Progressive-Automation?

Comment: It basically sounds like someone discovering TDD and BDD and perhaps coming from a background where the concept of writing tests at the same time is very new.  TDD and BDD have u write tests ahead of time, one by one, is simply part of the process and at the core of those techniques.  The amount of overlap means I would not personally use the term to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant True , too many terminologies are making testing world too confusing . Now I am getting confused with big bang integration testing and system testing after trying to read about progressive testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice article about progressive testing by Mphasis:

https://www.mphasis.com/home/thought-leadership/blog/test-automation-regressive-vs-progressive-automation.html

> Progressive automation is to automate almost every test case instead
>   of executing test cases manually. This is typically seen with the
>   projects that run in agile methodology. You will see in sprint
>   automation, which means, automation of the use cases that are
>   developed in the same sprint. WOW, this looks like a revolution, isn’t
>   it? When you automate every test case and during software development
>   the requirements or designs of the application are bound to change.
>   Then, the automation scripts have to be rewritten or redo completely
>   as we progress into next sprints.

When we refer more articles and tries to understand more about "Progressive" testing we could find that it resembles a lot with **test-driven development(TDD), Agile, V model etc.**

But from the

https://opkey.com/blog-detail.php/What-is-Progressive-Automation?

> What is Progressive Automation? Progressive automation is one of the
>   methods of automation technique where test modules are tested one
>   after the other. In progressive automation, automated test scripts are
>   written along with the development code, for faster testing and
>   identification of problems along with quick fixes. The scripts are
>   essentially written to test new software.

From here it sounds more **like overlapping of component testing, integration testing, and TDD**

So, from the readings, I would define

> "Progressive" testing as a "TDD approach to automated integration
>   test".

From my personal experience, "**Progressive**" testing where around 100% scenarios are automated is highly possible for API tests.

1. Here both dev and test team starts to work on the same user story. ( We copy-paste the development user story to  test user story)
2. The user-story explains the use case, expected inputs, expected outputs, performance requirements, and other API contracts.
3. Both the test team and the development team start codes for the user-story in the same sprint.
4. So by the time the product feature completes, tests are also complete.
5. We replace the stubs and drivers with actual data and test it locally.
6. Integrates the tests to pipeline
7. Developers initiate the build and the test runs in the pipeline,
8. The feature is pushed to system test only if all tests pass

**Replacing stubs and drivers, with actual component doesn't affect the test in any way as bot testers and developers use the same user story and API contract.**

But for **UI testing**,  this approach is not possible because we cannot automate without knowing the HTML DOM, how it will be rendered etc.

**Tool suggestion**: we used robotframework